# Regex using array.filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, filter

I'm trying to use a regular expression to filter the name column in a csv file that has be put into an object array.  Everything works fine if I type the exact value.

values I want "king" to match are below:

kingkong, king kong, king-kong, king_kong, king11, kongking, kong-king, kong_king, kong king, 11king

I've tried using filter and find methods but I want to use filter to return multiple values if they exist.  I have tried the following regex but can't figure out the proper sytax if it is even correct.

```
const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');
const user = "king";

CSVToJSON().fromFile("./locations.csv").then(source => {
    var found = source.filter(function(v, i){
    return ((v["name"]== /\bking.*/g));
})
```

Comment: Where is the regular expression?

Comment: That‘s not how one uses regular expressions in JS. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: sorry I am very new to javascript I have tried reading that page several times and but most of my problem was I was doing == instead of match like was pointed out to me below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach.

```
const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');


CSVToJSON().fromFile("./locations.csv").then(source => {
    var found = source.filter(function(v, i){
    return ((v["name"].match(/king/g)));
});
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much that is exactly what I needed!  Is there anyway to do the same thing but using a variable?  so king would be a variable that would change based on user input.

Comment: @gunner1980: If you search for `[javascript] regular expression variable` you should find an answer to that question.

Comment: This is equivalent with `v["name"].includes("king")` but much expensive.

Answer (score 0):

However, your sample patterns show that *king* might stand either at the beginning or at the end of the target (bot can't have both prefix and suffix). If I am right, that means you don't need regex for that.

```
const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');
const user = "king";

CSVToJSON().fromFile("./locations.csv").then(source => {
    var found = source.filter((v, i) => v.startsWith(user) || v.endsWith(user)) 
    /*rest of the code */
});
```

If *king* can stand anywhere, you can simply use `includes` instead.

Answer (score 0):

return statement could be something like

```
return ((/king/g).test(v["name"]));
```

OR

```
return ((v["name"].match(/king/g)));
```

Both should work

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked, I'm totally new to JavaScript:

```
      const user = args;
      var regex = new RegExp(user, "g");


      CSVToJSON().fromFile("./locations.csv").then(source => {
          var found = source.filter(function(v, i){
          return ((v["name"].match(regex)));
        })
```

Comment: Don't use regex if you don't have to. This pattern is equivalent with a simple `string.includes`.